Ubuntu can not read data from usb serial port
I have a device (barcode scanner) that when I plug into my laptop, this record is added when running lsusb command:
Bus 003 Device 070: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter
This is result of dmesg command:
[14764.599764] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 70 using xhci_hcd
[14764.757404] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.01
[14764.757414] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[14764.759963] ch341 3-4:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[14765.767914] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: failed to read break control: -110
[14765.767927] ch341-uart: probe of ttyUSB0 failed with error -110

There is no /dev/ttyUSB* port:
shefa@shefa:~$ sudo ls /dev/ttyUSB*
[sudo] password for shefa: 
ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB*': No such file or directory

Using Windows I can read data easily but I tested ubuntu 20.04, 22.04 and 24.04 and problem didn't solve.
What I tried:

Based on this /dev/ttyUSB0 not present in Ubuntu, I removed brltty package and sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER.
I also used following commands but no luck

apt update

apt upgrade

sudo modprobe -r ch341
sudo modprobe ch341

